# mysql query - accessing field without affecting output

Tags: mysql

I have 2 tables in mysql: tableA and tableB

```
tableA: idA
tableB: idB, name
```

Now i want to fire following query:

```
SELECT * FROM tableA WHERE idA in (1, 2, 3, 4);
```

idA and idB are exactly same. I want to access "name" field of tableB in the above query.

How do i do this???

Thanks alot for help
Regards

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a [MySQL JOIN](http://www.w3schools.com/Sql/sql_join.asp)

```
    SELECT tableB.name 
      FROM tableA 
INNER JOIN tableB ON tableA.idA=tableB.idB 
     WHERE idA in (1, 2, 3, 4);
```

Comment: Thanks for the cleanup, OMG Ponies :)

Answer (score 0):

Why select from TableA if you only need the id which is already in tableB?

```
SELECT idB, name FROM tableB where idB in (1, 2, 3, 4)
```

If you need to refer to the id field as idA, you can write

```
SELECT idB as idA, name FROM tableB where idB in (1, 2, 3, 4)
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks alot for help...

I just forgot the basic thing (thanks @yc you reminded me):

SELECT idA, name FROM tableA, tableB WHERE idA in (1, 2, 3, 4) and idA = idB;

Regards